# postMessage vs post

Tags: javascript, angular

Being in one site, we can use the following code as to navigate to a different domain by opening a new tab:

```
<form action="http://www.aka.com" method="post" target="_blank">
   <input name="firstName" type="text">
    <button >Test me </button>
</form>
```

Recently, I 've been working with `window.open` and as to communicate between different domains I 've used  `postMessage` method. I have the following queries:

- May I use `post` method, as presented above, to send data to the target window (*aka.com*)?
- If **aka.com** is an Angular app how may I grab the data sent (e.g. the value of `firstName`)?
- May I **replace** `postMessage`, as described above, with something like `using a form and post` method?

Comment: have you tried to do so?

Comment: The other domain would have to listen for the message and read the data that is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I use post method, as presented above, to send data to the target window (aka.com)?

No.

You can send data to a URL and have the response to the request for that URL appear in a new window.

> If aka.com is an Angular app how may I grab the data sent (e.g. the value of firstName)?

The server-side code on `aka.com` would have to provide it to the Angular code when it generated the page which loads that JS.

> May I replace postMessage, as described above, with something like using a form and post method?

Not without a major change of approach.

Answer (score 1):

> May I use post method, as presented above, to send data to the target window (aka.com)?
>
> May I replace postMessage, as described above, with something like using a form and post method?

window.postMessage() and a form POST method is essentially different things.

A form POST is used to send HTTP POST request to the targeted URL. What you're looking to do is sending data to a new window.

You shouldn't be looking to use a form to send data, instead use a (click) handler and do it manually.

> If aka.com is an Angular app how may I grab the data sent (e.g. the value of firstName)?

Since aka.com is an Angular app, it might not know when to check for the window data unless you listen for the 'message' event globally. One way is to send the data to a specific route in the Angular app so that it knows 'when Angular app is routed to this url, listen for window data, basically setting `window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);`.